# Updating 'My Domain' with live Marketing Cloud Connect integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are looking to update the custom URL applied as part of 'My Domain' within Salesforce - does anybody know if this will impact a live instance of Marketing Cloud Connect in any way?

To confirm, 'My Domain' is currently implemented but it will be changing from one value to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this in a client project lately. There will be **no effect** at all unless you have custom integrations on e.g. a cloudpage that for some reason reference the salesforce instance specific URL. This is very unlikely and I couldn't think of a reason for doing this.